# Why is the array output duplicated?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse a site, I want to get the source code of 2 pages. But as a result, I get a twice-repeated code of the first page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
URL_TEMPLATE = ["https://colmagzhan.kz/content/nasledie-velikih-novye-vozmoghnosti-razvitiyasovremennogoobrazovaniya/lang-kz",
                "https://colmagzhan.kz/content/provedena-razyyasnitelynaya-beseda-so-studentami-1-kursov-po-profilakt/lang-kz"]
r = [0]*len(URL_TEMPLATE)
for i in range(len(URL_TEMPLATE)):
    r[i] = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE[0])

for i in range(len(r)):
    print(r[i].text)
```

I'm trying parsing for the first time, I found instructions for beautifulsoup4 on the Habr website, but they talk about the possibility of parsing only one page. I need to parse many pages at once, I decided to do it using an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code if not very 'pythonic', even if [John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) gave you an answer, it's very recommended to reformat your code as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
URL_TEMPLATE = ["https://colmagzhan.kz/content/nasledie-velikih-novye-vozmoghnosti-razvitiyasovremennogoobrazovaniya/lang-kz",
                "https://colmagzhan.kz/content/provedena-razyyasnitelynaya-beseda-so-studentami-1-kursov-po-profilakt/lang-kz"]
r = []
for url in URL_TEMPLATE:
    r.append(requests.get(url))

for response in r:
    print(response.text)
```

This snippet of code also fixes your problem, which was:

```
r[i] = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE[0])
```

Even if your are iterating over `URL_TEMPLATE` you are still calling the first element when you do `URL_TEMPLATE[0]` at `request.get` function.

If you want to understand how for loops work in Python, i can recommend you [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop#:%7E:text=for%20loops%20are%20used%20when,executing%20the%20block%20each%20time.) entry from Python's wiki.

Also, if you want to write more 'pythonic' code, I recommend you [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/) guide.